# What is the equivalent of Menu: Format > Background Color > Black in code for a cell?

Tags: front-end

I've been trying to learn the front-end controls and reading about Cell, Style, etc.  However, I still haven't figured out how to control the appearance of a cell in code as well as I can do through the menu.  I must be missing something basic.

For example, how would you display this graphic in an all black cell?

```
data = Reverse[Sort[RandomReal[1, 5]]];
Module[{t = 0, len = Length[data], sum = Total[data]}, 
 Graphics[Table[{Hue[i/len], EdgeForm[Opacity[.8]], 
    Disk[{0, 0}, 1, {t, t += 2 Pi data[[i]]/sum}]}, {i, len}]]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SelectionMove[EvaluationNotebook[], Next, Cell]
SetOptions[NotebookSelection[EvaluationNotebook[]], Background -> Red]

data = Reverse[Sort[RandomReal[1, 5]]];
Module[{t = 0, len = Length[data], sum = Total[data]}, 
 Graphics[Table[{Hue[i/len], EdgeForm[Opacity[.8]], 
    Disk[{0, 0}, 1, {t, t += 2 Pi data[[i]]/sum}]}, {i, len}]]]
```

[image]

To change the background for the  next cell group:

***Before:***

[image]

***After executing the cell group with `SelectionMove[...]...`***

[image]

Comment: That would make a good demonstration project for Wolfram, but it is certainly searchable here.